# Im getting an error in the shell whenever enter is pressed when I'm changing the board size

Tags: python

Have a look at ChangeBoardSize()
It'll be part of the while loop that I have to change but I'm not sure what to change or what to change it to.
I would appreciate any help for this to be done in anyway.
Ignore this but now because I am just trying to get the character count up so that I can post this.

```
import random

def SetUpGameBoard(Board, Boardsize, PlayerInitials, ComputerInitials):
    for Row in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
      for Column in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
        if (Row == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 and Column == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 + 1) or (Column == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 and Row == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 + 1):
          Board[Row][Column] = ComputerInitials
        elif (Row == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 + 1 and Column == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 + 1) or (Column == (BoardSize + 1) // 2 and Row == (BoardSize + 1) // 2):
          Board[Row][Column] = PlayerInitials
        else:
          Board[Row][Column] = " "

def ChangeInitials(PlayerName):
    print("Enter the initials for", PlayerName, "'s piece")
    PlayerInitials = input()
    PlayerInitials = PlayerInitials.upper()
    print("Enter the initials for the computer's piece")
    ComputerInitials = input()
    ComputerInitials = ComputerInitials.upper()
    return ComputerInitials, PlayerInitials


def ChangeBoardSize():
    BoardSize = int(input("Enter a board size (between 4 and 9): "))
    while not(BoardSize >= 4 and BoardSize <= 9):
        BoardSize = int(input("Enter a board size (between 4 and 9): "))
        if BoardSize != [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
            ChangeBoardSize()
        elif BoardSize == " ":
            ChangeBoardSize()
    return BoardSize

def GetHumanPlayerMove(PlayerName):
    print(PlayerName, "enter the coodinates of the square where you want to place your piece: ", end="")
    Coordinates = input()
    if Coordinates.isdigit():
        MoveValid = True

    return int(Coordinates)

def GetComputerPlayerMove(BoardSize):
    return random.randint(1, BoardSize) * 10 + random.randint(1, BoardSize)

def GameOver(Board, BoardSize):
    for Row in range(1 , BoardSize + 1):
      for Column in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
        if Board[Row][Column] == " ":
          return False
    return True

def GetPlayersName():
    PlayerName = input("What is your name? ")
    return PlayerName

def CheckIfMoveIsValid(Board, Move):
    Row = Move % 10
    Column = Move // 10
    MoveIsValid = False
    if Board[Row][Column] == " ":
      MoveIsValid = True
    return MoveIsValid

def GetPlayerScore(Board, BoardSize, Piece):
    Score = 0
    for Row in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
      for Column in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
        if Board[Row][Column] == Piece:
          Score = Score + 1
    return Score

def CheckIfThereArePiecesToFlip(Board, BoardSize, StartRow, StartColumn, RowDirection, ColumnDirection):
    RowCount = StartRow + RowDirection
    ColumnCount = StartColumn + ColumnDirection
    FlipStillPossible = True
    FlipFound = False
    OpponentPieceFound = False
    while RowCount <= BoardSize and RowCount >= 1 and ColumnCount >= 1 and ColumnCount <= BoardSize and FlipStillPossible and not FlipFound:
      if Board[RowCount][ColumnCount] == " ":
        FlipStillPossible = False
      elif Board[RowCount][ColumnCount] != Board[StartRow][StartColumn]:
        OpponentPieceFound = True
      elif Board[RowCount][ColumnCount] == Board[StartRow][StartColumn] and not OpponentPieceFound:
        FlipStillPossible = False
      else:
        FlipFound = True
      RowCount = RowCount + RowDirection
      ColumnCount = ColumnCount + ColumnDirection
    return FlipFound

def FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, StartRow, StartColumn, RowDirection, ColumnDirection):
    FlipFound = CheckIfThereArePiecesToFlip(Board, BoardSize, StartRow, StartColumn, RowDirection, ColumnDirection)
    if FlipFound:
      RowCount = StartRow + RowDirection
      ColumnCount = StartColumn + ColumnDirection
      while Board[RowCount][ColumnCount] != " " and Board[RowCount][ColumnCount] != Board[StartRow][StartColumn]:
        if Board[RowCount][ColumnCount] == "H":
          Board[RowCount][ColumnCount] = "C"
        else:
          Board[RowCount][ColumnCount] = "H"
        RowCount = RowCount + RowDirection
        ColumnCount = ColumnCount + ColumnDirection

def MakeMove(Board, BoardSize, Move, HumanPlayersTurn):
    Row = Move % 10
    Column = Move // 10
    if HumanPlayersTurn:
      Board[Row][Column] = "H"
    else:
      Board[Row][Column] = "C"
    FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, Row, Column, 1, 0)
    FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, Row, Column, -1, 0)
    FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, Row, Column, 0, 1)
    FlipOpponentPiecesInOneDirection(Board, BoardSize, Row, Column, 0, -1)


def PrintLine(BoardSize):
    print("   ", end="")
    for Count in range(1, BoardSize * 2):
      print("_", end="")
    print()

def DisplayGameBoard(Board, BoardSize):
    print()
    print("  ", end="")
    for Column in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
      print(" ", end="")
      print(Column, end="")
    print()
    PrintLine(BoardSize)
    for Row in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
      print(Row, end="")
      print(" ", end="")
      for Column in range(1, BoardSize + 1):
        print("|", end="")
        print(Board[Row][Column], end="")
      print("|")
      PrintLine(BoardSize)
      print()

def DisplayMenu():
    print("(p)lay game")
    print("(e)nter name")
    print("(c)hange board size")
    print("(i)initials change")
    print("(a)lter piece name")
    print("(q)uit")
    print()

def GetMenuChoice(PlayerName):
    print(PlayerName, "enter the letter of your chosen option: ", end="")
    Choice = input()
    return Choice

def CreateBoard():
    Board = []
    for Count in range(BoardSize + 1):
      Board.append([])
      for Count2 in range(BoardSize + 1):
        Board[Count].append("")
    return Board

def PlayGame(PlayerName, BoardSize, PlayerInitials, ComputerInitials):
    Board = CreateBoard()
    SetUpGameBoard(Board, BoardSize, PlayerInitials, ComputerInitials)
    HumanPlayersTurn = False
    while not GameOver(Board, BoardSize):
      HumanPlayersTurn = not HumanPlayersTurn
      DisplayGameBoard(Board, BoardSize)
      MoveIsValid = False
      while not MoveIsValid:
        if HumanPlayersTurn:
          Move = GetHumanPlayerMove(PlayerName)
        else:
          Move = GetComputerPlayerMove(BoardSize)
        MoveIsValid = CheckIfMoveIsValid(Board, Move)
      if not HumanPlayersTurn:
        print("Press the Enter key and the computer will make its move")
        input()
      MakeMove(Board, BoardSize, Move, HumanPlayersTurn)
    DisplayGameBoard(Board, BoardSize)
    HumanPlayerScore = GetPlayerScore(Board, BoardSize, "H")
    ComputerPlayerScore = GetPlayerScore(Board, BoardSize, "C")
    if HumanPlayerScore > ComputerPlayerScore:
      print("Well done", PlayerName, ", you have won the game!")
    elif HumanPlayerScore == ComputerPlayerScore:
      print("That was a draw!")
    else:
      print("The computer has won the game!")
    print()


random.seed()
BoardSize = 6
PlayerName = ""
Choice = ""
PlayerInitials = 'H'
ComputerInitials = 'C'

while Choice.lower() != "q":    #.lower() makes any allows uppercase input
    DisplayMenu()
    Choice = GetMenuChoice(PlayerName)
    if Choice.lower() == "p":
        PlayGame(PlayerName, BoardSize, ComputerInitials, PlayerInitials)
    elif Choice.lower() == "e":
        PlayerName = GetPlayersName()
    elif Choice.lower() == 'a':
        ChangePieceName()
    elif Choice.lower() == 'i':
        ChangeInitials(PlayerName)
    elif Choice.lower() == "c":
        BoardSize = ChangeBoardSize()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem because you don't handle entering characters other than numbers so it fails on line 39

```
return int(Coordinates) # if Coordinates is not str convertable to int it fails
```

So you need to do something like

```
def GetHumanPlayerMove(PlayerName):
    print(PlayerName, "enter the coodinates of the square where you want to place your piece: ", end="")
    Coordinates = input()
    if Coordinates.isdigit():
        MoveValid = True
    try:
        return int(Coordinates)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter number")
        print(PlayerName, "enter the coodinates of the square where you want to place your piece: ", end="")
        return GetHumanPlayerMove(PlayerName)
```

Or create a `while` loop like you did below. So

```
while not isinstance(Coordinates, int): ...
```

The function will look like this

```
def GetHumanPlayerMove(PlayerName):
    MoveValid = False
    while not MoveValid:
        print(PlayerName, "enter the coodinates of the square where you want to place your piece: ", end="")
        Coordinates = input()
        if Coordinates.isdigit():
            MoveValid = True
    return int(Coordinates)
```